# regular expression, take first three lines or all lines less than 3 lines in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

In java, how to write a regex to take first 3 lines if there is more than 3 lines OR take all lines if there is less than or equal to 3 lines?

I used the https://regexr.com/ to verify my own solution, failed. Then I asked the online chat group IRC #regex, the expert gives me answer within 1 minute. So I believe I shall share the knowledge here.

Comment: How about `^(?:.*\r?\n){1,3}` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6sEGqm/2/))? It's plain-vanilla regex so I would think it would work in spunk.

Comment: You are right. Thanks！@CarySwoveland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[^\n]*\n?[^\n]*\n?[^\n]*\n?
```

One could verify it at website: https://regexr.com/